# how to get an image from a URL with no extension?

Tags: image, url, file-extension

https://lh4.ggpht.com/HSXdsQpFEOTgh0QywV4NzNJIPADnWnkCVOsMmQkIgG9K08pQcwpNiWlu3Ls73mzYMTM=h230

How to get the extension or the image itself from this URL using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

But it doesn't have an extension. And it doesn't have a content-disposition header to give you a clue.

When downloading this image you need to check the content-type header to find out the image format.

Comment: in that case, how would i get the image from that?

Comment: I have no idea. You didn't specify any detail whatsoever in your question. You did not list any technologies you're using, you didn't say do you want to do it server side, or from the browser. Nothing.

Comment: Sorry. I am using PHP for this.